# What is a word similar to "multiplier" but for addition (or subtraction)

Tags: mathematics

A *multiplier* is a number by which another number is multiplied. What do you call a number by which another number is added or subtracted?

Comment: It's the **addend**.

Comment: Genius. Does that work for subtraction as well, or is the terminology different? By the way, you should make that an official answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: **minuend** minus **subtrahend** equals (directed difference)  ( see at http://www.factmonster.com/ipka/A0881931.html ; but 'difference' is always taken as the absolute value, even when taking a larger from a smaller number, which this doesn't cover)

Comment: Got it. So for *addition* it's **addend** and for *subtraction* it's **subtrahend**. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the *multiplier* (that which multiplies) and the *multiplicand* (that which is to be multiplied).

For subtraction there is the *subtrahend* (that which is to be subtracted) and the *minuend* (that which is to be diminished).

For division there is the *divisor* (that which divides) and the *dividend* (that which is to be divided).

These words with *-and* or *-end* are Latin future participles.

Comment: Your answer was a bit more straightforward. For those looking for a quick answer, it might be useful to add another sentence about **addend** in the same format. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of mathematical points to make which inform the English involved.

(1) 'Addition' (yes, simple addition!) covers two major operations:

(a) Combination of two elements from a set (a binary operation) (eg 3 marbles + 2 marbles = 5 marbles).

(b) Transformation of one element into another (a unary operation) (eg a 3cm-long worm grows by 2cm )

Both are modelled identically by 3 + 2 = 5, but a transformation arrow with '+2' over the top is fitting for the transformation.

In the first case, addend + addend = sum / total

In the second case, augend + addend = sum / total.

(2) We've had a thread discussing the fact that there is no agreed term for the result of a subtraction; 'directed difference' is used by some.

Answer (score -1):

Probably, the answer is the "addend" and "subtrahend"