# Is there a word that is equivalent to handicap but doesn't imply a negative effect?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine a scenario where the default value for a temperature is 20°C. Is there a word that you can use to say that if you do X you add 2°C to that value, if you do Y you minus 7°C to that value and if you do Z you add 1°C.

I want to explain that `for each action you apply a ...'

I can think of two words that are similar:

You could say you apply a handicap - as you would in golf

Or you apply a multiplier

The following question :[What is a word similar to "multiplier" but for addition (or subtraction)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112574/what-is-a-word-similar-to-multiplier-but-for-addition-or-subtraction) suggests addend or subtrahend but again this implies a positive or negative direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [adjustment](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adjustment):

> - A modification, fluctuation, or correction: *an adjustment in the consumer price index.*

(AHD)

Comment: I think a combination of your answer and Centaurus is best - an adjustment factor doesn't imply any particular method of changing a value or any direction but simply that it is changed.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use  **"a correction factor"** for the desired temperature.

For each action you apply a temperature correction factor.

> - A correction factor is any mathematical adjustment made to a calculation to account for deviations in either the sample or the method of measurement.
>
> Read more : http://www.ehow.com/facts_7268119_correction-factor_.html

Or, if your intention is not to correct an error,  **"a regulation"** seems to fit.

- For each action, you apply a **temperature regulation**.

Comment: I dont think correction factor is quite right as you are not trying to adjust a value to correct error but make an adjustment to one based off an action (http://www.yourdictionary.com/correction-factor) thank you for your help though, its closer that what I got to!

Answer (score 2):

### Modifier

From [ODO](http://www.bing.com/search?q=modifier&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=modifier&sc=8-5&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=0040599704d14547b082bdf4eb43455b):

> a person or thing that makes partial or minor changes to something

This is a common usage for applying changes to the outcomes of die rolls in wargaming and RPGs.